# For Loop C# but startin from certain index and keep Looping until it reach the index again

Tags: c#

I got some question that i cannot wrap my head around
I want to create a for loop that start from certain index(not 0) and looping back from 0 until it reach that certain index.

now i know how to start at certain index Like this ->

```
        int startIndex = 3
        int max = 5

        for(int i = startIndex; i <= max ; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(i);
        }
```

that code will return me:

3

4

5

But how do i iterate it back again?
what i want to have is like this order:

3

4

5

0

1

2

Comment: Don't use a `for` loop. Use a `do` or `while` loop and put your index-calculation logic in the loop.

Comment: It all depends on the purpose of this, so you just want to have these numbers? Or more numbers? Or do you want to use them as indexes for an other array? Do you want to rotate (that's what is called) an array of data? We need to know what underlying problem you are trying to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the modulo operation (`%`). It calculates the remainder of an integer division.

E.g. `8 % 6 = 2`, because `8 / 6 = 1, remainder = 2`.

```cs
int n = 6;
int startIndex = 3;
for (int i = startIndex; i < startIndex + n ; i++)
{
    Debug.Log(i % n);
}
```

`% 6` will subtract 6 until the number becomes smaller than 6.

| i | i % 6 |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 0 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 8 | 2 |

The modulo operation is often used to create a circular behavior.

Comment: Nice one Olivier!!
Clean and simplee..! :D
Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
int startIndex = 3;
int max = 5;

for (int i = startIndex; i <= max; i++)
{
    if (i == 5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        i = 0;
    }
    else if (i == 0)
    {
        i = 3;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Just write `Debug.Log` instead of `Console.WriteLine()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Enumerable class and method Range, which can produce values.

First parameter mean first number of sequence and the second one how many of numbers you want.

```
var myInts = Enumerable.Range(startIndex, max - startIndex + 1).Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, startIndex)).ToArray();
```

UPDATE:

I realize, that concat method is very harm for memory, in result garbage collector must clean up 3 sequenses, so next code is much better:

```
var myInts = Enumerable.Range(0, max + 1).OrderBy(i => i < startIndex).ToArray();
```

In this case, sequence created once and then just sorted by rule.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite clean, and only uses simple incrementation:

```cs
const int startIndex = 3;
const int max = 5;
var i = startIndex;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
} while ((i = i + 1 <= max ? i + 1 : 0) != startIndex);
```

This prints:

```
3
4
5
0
1
2
```

`i = i + 1 <= max ? i + 1 : 0` this logic works well because it tries to increment until `max`, otherwise starts from zero and stops at `startIndex`, without unnecessary memory allocations.